# How to fix an error where a concept declaration has no storage class or storage type?

Tags: c++

I got this code from a a github repository. I copied the code exactly as it is however I am still getting an error that says the declaration has no storage class or type specifier where it says concept on the first template declaration. Here is the code, the error is where the comment is:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_trait>
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
concept bool Averageable() { // Here is where the error appears, at concept
    return std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value && requires(T a, T b) {
        { a += b } -> T; 
        { a / size_t{ 1 } } -> T;  
    };
}

template<Averageable T>
T mean(const T* values, size_t length) {
    T result(); 
    for (size_t i{}; i < length; i++) {
        result += values[i]; 
    }
    return result / length; 
}

int main() {
    const double nums_d[] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };
    const auto result1 = mean(nums_d, 4);
    printf("double: %f\n", result1);

    const float nums_f[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    const auto result2 = mean(nums_f, 4);
    printf("float: %f\n", result2);

    const size_t nums_c[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    const auto result3 = mean(nums_c, 4);
    printf("float: %d\n", result3);
}
```

The expected output is:

```
double: 2.500000
float: 2.500000
size_t: 2
```

Comment: Make sure your compiler actually supports concepts. It's a pretty big feature and still early.

Comment: The "concept bool" suggests this code was meant for the concepts TS. Does the github repo say which compilers/versions support the code?

Comment: no it does not sadly.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 uses a different syntax for concepts. Your code probably targets some old concepts proposal.

Also there are few typos here: `T result();`, `#include <type_trait>`, ...

Here's a fixed version:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept Averageable = 
    std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value && requires(T a, T b) {
        { a += b } -> std::convertible_to<T>; 
        { a / size_t{ 1 } } -> std::convertible_to<T>;  
    };

template<Averageable T>
T mean(const T* values, size_t length) {
    T result = 0; 
    for (size_t i{}; i < length; i++) {
        result += values[i]; 
    }
    return result / length; 
}

int main() {
    const double nums_d[] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };
    const auto result1 = mean(nums_d, 4);
    printf("double: %f\n", result1);

    const float nums_f[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    const auto result2 = mean(nums_f, 4);
    printf("float: %f\n", result2);

    const size_t nums_c[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    const auto result3 = mean(nums_c, 4);
    printf("float: %zu\n", result3);
}
```

It works on GCC 10 [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6enstp).

Comment: I've tried your code, however I am getting another error saying that: "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit"

Comment: @wtsegars It's not an actual compiler error. (Your IDE can't find some include file.) Does it actually compile for you?

Comment: It won't even compile for me.

Comment: @wtsegars Can you post the exact error message then? Are you sure your compiler supports concepts?

Comment: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" is the specific error that I am getting. And the compiler that I am using is g++.

Comment: @wtsegars What does `g++ --version` output?

Comment: If I did it right, I think it said that I'm using version 4.2.1

Comment: @wtsegars If you're not sure, post the entire output of `g++ --version`. GCC 4.2.1 is incredibly old, it was released 13 years ago! Also, can you post the full error message?

Comment: that was the full error message. It won't let me even compile it.

Comment: It's almost looking like I am missing the file for the concepts header.

Comment: @wtsegars *"that was the full error message"* No it wasn't. If you're missing `<concepts>`, it should've been mentioned in the error. Looks like `<concepts>` was added in GCC 10, so if you don't have it, you need to update your compiler.

Comment: Already tried to update gcc, it said that I have the latest version

Comment: @wtsegars GCC 10 was not released yet (as a stable version). If you don't want to wait, ask a new question about installing the development version of it. (Don't forget to tell us what OS you use and how you installed GCC.)

Comment: I don't think that this is a compiler error because I tried typing the code into a different development application (in this case Xcode) and it came back with a similar error saying "unknown type name 'concept'". The development application that I was using before was vscode. I didn't even get to run or compile it yet.

Comment: @wtsegars It doesn't really matter what your IDE says. They are not perfect, and sometimes they disagree with compilers. Open your terminal and compile the code from there.

Comment: Just tried it got this error back:                                                            averageable2.cpp:6:1: error: unknown type name 'concept'
concept bool Averageable() {
^
averageable2.cpp:6:9: error: expected unqualified-id
concept bool Averageable() {
        ^
2 errors generated.

Comment: @wtsegars Weird that it doesn't complain about `<concepts>`. In any case, if it doesn't work for you, your compiler is too old.

Comment: Well I did add the <concepts> header in another build attempt and it said: averageable2.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'concepts' file not found
#include <concepts>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Comment: Additionally I tried to update gcc via Homebrew and it said that I am using the most current version (9.3.0).

Comment: @wtsegars We're going in circles. I already told you that you need at least GCC 10, and that since it's not officially released yet, installing it won't be as easy. If you want to know how to install it on Mac, post a separate question.